# $\left \langle (A^{2}+B^{2})x,x \right \rangle\geq \left \langle (AB+BA)x,x \right \rangle$ if $A$ and $B$ are symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, symmetric-matrices

Let be $A$ and $B$ two real matrices of $n \times  n$. And $\left \langle , \right \rangle$ denotes the usual inner product in $\mathbb{R}^{n}.$

> Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are symmetric then $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ it satisfies:
>
> \begin{align*} \left \langle (A^{2}+B^{2})x,x  \right \rangle\geq \left
>  \langle (AB+BA)x,x \right \rangle \end{align*}
> *Hint*: Consider $\left \langle (A-B)^{2}x,x \right \rangle$

What I think I can do is to note that:

\begin{align*}
\left \langle A^{2}+B^{2})x,x  \right \rangle&=\left \langle A^2x,x \right \rangle + \left \langle B^2x,x \right \rangle\\\left \langle AB+BA)x,x  \right \rangle&=\left \langle AB,x \right \rangle + \left \langle BA,x \right \rangle
\end{align*}

And then try to prove in general that:

\begin{align*}
\left \langle A^2x,x  \right \rangle&\geq\left \langle ABx,x \right \rangle\\
\end{align*}

Neverthless, I don't know how to use the hint and the fact that the matrices are symmetric. Can you help me please? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $(A-B)^2 = (A^2 + B^2) - (AB + BA)$
- The eigenvalues of $(A-B)^2$ are nonnegative so $\langle (A-B)^2 x, x \rangle \ge 0$ for any $x$.

Comment: Thank you! But, where do I have to use the fact that the matrices are symmetric? @angryavian

Comment: $A$ and $B$ being symmetric implies that $A-B$ is symmetric, so $(A-B)^T(A-B) = (A-B)^2$, which implies the second point in the answer.